# Data is not being stored in the database using Java Servlets, Postgres and JS

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, servlets, xmlhttprequest

Register Java Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import alcq.db.org.DB;
import alcq.db.org.PropertiesReader;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class register
 */
@WebServlet("/register")
public class register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public register() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject reqBody = new JSONObject(request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        DB db = new DB();

        String query = PropertiesReader.getInstance().getValue("queryRegister");
        json.put("query", db.executeQuery(query, reqBody.getString("name"), reqBody.getString("lastname"), reqBody.getString("username"), reqBody.getString("password"), reqBody.getString("email")));
        db.closeCon();
        out.print(json.toString());
    }

}
```

DB Setup

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class DB {

    private ResultSet rs;
    private ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private Connection con;
    private PropertiesReader prop = PropertiesReader.getInstance();
    private JSONArray table;
    private JSONObject row;

    public DB(){
        try {
            Class.forName(prop.getValue("dbDriver"));
            this.con= DriverManager.getConnection(prop.getValue("dbUrl"),prop.getValue("dbUser"),prop.getValue("dbPassword"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONArray executeQuery(String query, Object... values) {
        try {
            this.pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                this.pstmt.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
            }
            this.rs = this.pstmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return this.getTable(this.rs);
    }

    public JSONArray getTable(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            this.rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            rs.last();
            table = new JSONArray();
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                row = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 1; i <= this.rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    row.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i), rs.getObject(i));
                }
                table.put(row);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return table;
    }

    public void execute(String query, Object... values) {
        try {
            this.pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                this.pstmt.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
            }

            this.pstmt.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeCon() {
        try {
            this.con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

PropertiesReader

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesReader {
    private static PropertiesReader propr = new PropertiesReader();
    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private InputStream input = null;

    private PropertiesReader() {
        try {
            String catalina = System.getProperty("catalina.base");
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("catalina.base"));
            input = new FileInputStream(catalina + "\\conf\\connection.properties");
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static PropertiesReader getInstance () {
        return propr;
    }
    public String getValue(String key){
        return prop.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

Register.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src ='./js/XHR.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

            <form action="register" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="first name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="last name">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username" pattern="^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{3,29}$" title="Usernames can contain characters a-z, 0-9, underscores and periods. The username cannot contain symbols or blank space. Min length is 3 and Max length is 30 chars.">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$" title="- at least 8 characters 
- must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, and 1 number 
- Can contain special characters">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onclick = 'request()'>Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var xhr = new XHR();

            function $(id){
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

            function request() {
                var name     = $('name').value,
                    lastname = $('lastname').value,
                    username = $('username').value,
                    email    = $('email').value,
                    password = $('password').value;
                xhr.get('./register',{name:name, lastname:lastname, username:username, email:email, password:password},{}).then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
            };

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

XHR

```
function XHR(){
    var jsonToParams= function(json){
        var res="";
        for (var attr in json){
            if (res===""){
                res=attr+"="+json[attr];
            } else {
                res+="&"+attr+"="+json[attr];
            }           
        }
        return res;
    };
    var xmlObject=null;
    var data=null;
    var err=null;
    var xhr = function(method,url,params,callback){
        try{
            xmlObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlObject.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlObject.status===200&&xmlObject.readyState===4){
                    data= JSON.parse(xmlObject.responseText);
                    callback(null,data);
                }
            }
            xmlObject.open(method,url,true);
            xmlObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            if(method==="post"){
                xmlObject.send(params);
            }
            else{
                xmlObject.send();
            }
    }
    catch(err){
        callback(err,null);
    }

}

    this.post=function(url,params,callback){
        params=typeof params==="string"?
        params:jsonToParams(params);
        xhr("post",url,params,callback);
    }
}
```

PD: My queryRegister: queryRegister = INSERT INTO app_user(name, lastname, username, password, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

So basically I think that I have done everything alright so far but It is not sending the data to my database why? Do I need to use promise?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does your application produce any logs?

Comment: @Olaf nope I am not recieving any error

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong, but it looks like you are trying to execute an INSERT statement and calling Satement.executeQuery() method for that. I believe the appropriate method for that is Statement.executeUpdate().

Comment: @olaf I am trying to insert statement yeah, let me try it, could we speak in private?

Comment: I believe you need at least 20 rep to use StackOverflow chat.

Comment: @olaf Do you have an email or something?